# Появление/скрытие

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на *li* появлялся один *background*, а если я нажимаю на второй *li*, то на первом *background* убирается и ставится на втором?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".uslugi a").click(function(){
        $(this).hover(function(){
            $(this).css("background-color","#000");
        })  
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути, вы в своем вопросе уже и ответили на него) Т.е. надо сбрасывать его на другом и добавлять свойство у того, на который кликнули. А вообще лучше не добавлять свойство css через скрипт. А лучше определить свойство активного элемента в css, а уже в коде добавлять класс данного свойства или удалять

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.uslugi').click(function() {
    $('.uslugi').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<li class="uslugi">1</li>
<li class="uslugi">2</li>
<li class="uslugi">3</li>
<li class="uslugi">4</li>
<li class="uslugi">5</li>
```

Comment: А подскажите, почему если я пишу $(function(){
    $(".uslugi a").click(function(){
            $(".uslugi a").css("background","none");
            $(this).css({"background":"#303030", "color":"#fff"});
    });
});то цвет теста у всех li сохраняется, а не остаётся только у одного выбранного ответа

Comment: @ChromeChrome потому, что вы сбрасываете у всех только background =) для сброса цвета нужно еще color дописывать. Также, как тут `$(this).css({"background":"#303030", "color":"#fff"})`, только наоборот)))  .P.S. Стилей у вас может быть определенно для данного действия очень много. Именно поэтому я очень рекомендую делать через стили и присваивания элементу лишь класса. Не придется писать код типа `$('.someClass').css({a looooot of styles that can be used for clear element and other stuff})`. Да и css проще править